# PETSC. Run program without using mpiexec

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, petsc, mpiexec

How i can run program, that  writen using PETSC, in multiple threads without `./mpiexec -n <>`?

Maybe i need init *MPI* separately? Can u get reference to example how init *MPI* with `PetscInitialize()` in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just running the binary?

Comment: For some MPI implementations, just running the binary will work.